# Taking Esri Maps for Office OFFLINE

Tags: offline, esri-maps-office

Is Esri Maps for Office available offline? AKA, if I build a beautiful PPT with an interactive map, can I bring this presentation to a client or conference and present to them without having to connect to the Internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your license type, you may be able to borrow a license (In my screenshot below, my home use does not include the option, but concurrent licenses do, this is where you would find the option). This allows you to check out a license for a few days, so great for presentations, traveling or any time you know you may be disconnected.

Start Menu-->ArcGIS-->ArcGIS Administrator

[image]

[ArcGIS Link for License Borrowing](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/get-started/administering-desktop/borrowing-and-returning-licenses.htm)